# Not able to download dependency via yarn from GitHub NPM registry (npm.pkg.github.com)

Tags: github, npm, yarnpkg

I have started using GitHub NPM registry for one of the project which is a monorepo. I am using `Lerna` to manage it which uses `yarn` as package client.

I was able to publish the package to registry, and i am able to download the same via `npm install` command, but the same is not working with `yarn add` command. It throws the following error -

```sh
error https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/MY_USERNAME/MY_PACKAGE_NAME/PACKAGE_VERSION/HASH Integrity checked failed for "PACKAGE_NAME" (none of the specified algorithms are supported)


info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I have tried creating the lock file manually ( which isn't recommended ) but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to post the solution that worked for me:

```
yarn install --update-checksums
```